PysimpleGUI handling pictures with text in frames
I have used tkinter to organize pictures with text inside various frames on a canvas with a scrollbar. (as can be seen in the picture). I'm really struggling to achieve same functionalities with pysimplegui. I need help on creating a layout using Image(),Text() and Frame() Elements. I have also tried to manipulate the layout with Column Element without success. Looping through the arrangement really stops my progress.

Tell us more, it looks like that there's nothing about your project and your problem.

I'm unsure whether the picture was included or not

To avoid the location issue for image and text, I build a Image Column for it.
If you need to work dynamically with adding elements, Image, Frame, remember to call window.refresh() and scrollbale_column.contents_changed() after it, so it will update all content to keep the scrollar work correctly.
Example Code
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Image(sg.Column):

    def __init__(self, source, text):
        layout = [[sg.Image(source)], [sg.Text(text, size=8, justification="center")]]
        super().__init__(layout, element_justification="center")

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 11))

emoji = {"Happy":sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST, "SADLY":sg.EMOJI_BASE64_SAD_LIST}

columns = 10
column_layout = []
for title, lst in emoji.items():
    frame_layout, line = [], []
    limit = len(lst) - 1
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        line.append(Image(item, f"{title} {i+1}"))
        if i % columns == columns - 1 or i == limit:
            frame_layout.append(line)
            line = []
    column_layout.append([sg.Frame(title, frame_layout)])

layout = [[sg.Column(column_layout, scrollable=True, vertical_scroll_only=True)]]
sg.Window("Scrollable Frames with Images", layout).read(close=True)


